# Fade-In Several Elements with JQuery, Each with Random Delay

Tags: jquery, fadein

Trying to use JQuery to make several elements, each in their own DIV, phase in with their own "delay" and "fadeIn" values.  I have it working in [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthewschenker/at7c82Lk/30/), but is this the most efficient way to go?  In the live site, I will pass a random number via PHP for the delay and fadeIn values.

Here is the JQuery:

```
$(".fade1").hide(0).delay(500).fadeIn(500);
$(".fade2").hide(0).delay(800).fadeIn(1750);
$(".fade3").hide(0).delay(1000).fadeIn(3500);
$(".fade4").hide(0).delay(1500).fadeIn(5000);
```

Comment: It'd be inefficient if you have a lot of elements in the parent container `.fade_container`. How about a loop that goes through the children of that? You can then bind `.fadeIn` to each of those with an increasing interval on both `.delay` and `.fadein`

Answer (score 1):

You can write a tiny jQuery plugin script like below:

```
$.fn.hideNFadeIn = function (opts) {
    var options = opts;
    this.each(function (i) {
        $(this).hide(0).delay(options.delay[i]).fadeIn(options.fadeIn[i]);
    });
};
$('.fade1, .fade2, .fade3, .fade4').hideNFadeIn({
    delay: [500, 800, 1000, 1500],
    fadeIn: [500, 1750, 3500, 5000]
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/at7c82Lk/38/)

Comment: Nice idea!  I have updated my original Fiddle with this.